# JS "Google form to discord channel" problem

Tags: javascript

I encountered a problem with the code for sending Google forms via a webhook to a discord channel. Each response in the form requires a specific tag in the message, but when I found part of this code on the Internet, messages after submitting the form stopped going through altogether. Help, what needs to be done? I’m even worse than a beginner, this is my first time doing something like this and I can’t figure it out. Thank you in advance.

Here's the code itself:

```
const POST_URL = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1183408138548944986/hASQpt-8i2KnihhG862PcjwziempEKaplxnvsgNnehaWkK3tSCdG_K3oo0tgMJClYTuJ";

const USERNAME = "Заявка на перевод между отделами"; 
const AVATAR_URL = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1162425492272595066/1183438920894120047/d80ca90e11aec5f4c324ec7445a1fd12f8209b14_512.png"; 
const CONTENT = "<@&1123258457349431387> Поступила новая заявка на перевод."; 
const COLOR = 6017436; // Цвета тут: https://www.spycolor.com const TITLE = ""; 
const FOOTER = "Автор формы: Kiba Fubuyama"; const TIMESTAMP = true;

function onSubmit(e) { const response = e.response.getItemResponses(); let items = [];
for (const responseAnswer of response) {
    const question = responseAnswer.getItem().getTitle();
    const answer = responseAnswer.getResponse();
    let parts = []

    try {
        parts = answer.match(/[\s\S]{1,1024}/g) || [];
    } catch (e) {
        parts = answer;
    }

    if (!answer) {
        continue;
    }

    for (const [index, part] of Object.entries(parts)) {
        if (index == 0) {
            items.push({
                "name": question,
                "value": part,
                "inline": false
            });
        } else {
            items.push({
                "name": question.concat(" (cont.)"),
                "value": part,
                "inline": false
            });
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          const question = response[i].getItem().getTitle(), answer = response[i].getResponse();
          if (answer == "") continue;
          items.push({ "name": question, "value": answer });

          if (answer.includes('SED')) {
          const roleId = answer.split('SED')[1];
          mention += "<@&704605675476746320>" ;
    }
          if (answer.includes('PAB')) {
          const roleId = answer.split('PAB')[1];
          mention += "<@&704606021070618626>" ;
    }
         if (answer.includes('CPB')) {
         const roleId = answer.split('CPB')[1];
         mention += "<@&704606020651057203>" ;
   }
         if (answer.includes('IAD')) {
          const roleId = answer.split('IAD')[1];
         mention += "<@&1117845843702198354>" ;
    }
  }
}
var TIME = "";
if (TIMESTAMP) {
  TIME = new Date().toISOString();
}
    }
var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    "payload": JSON.stringify({
        "content": CONTENT,
        "embeds": [{
            "title": TITLE,
            "color": COLOR,
            "fields": items,
            "footer": {
                "text": FOOTER
            },
            "timestamp": TIME
        }],
        username: USERNAME,
        avatar_url: AVATAR_URL,
    })
};

UrlFetchApp.fetch(POST_URL, options);
```

};